# django + mysql, storing ip address including ranges

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, ip

I need an efficient way to store IP address.
The query I would like to do is if IP is in the table (or in range).
I need to store ranges like,

```
192.168.0.1 - 192.168.1.255
```

And also individual IPs.

Since there are many records I think it will be a waste to store them one by one. But I would go for that if that would be the best.
Django does have [GenericIPAddressField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#genericipaddressfield) field, but it does not store ranges.

So what is my best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, both involve the use of two columns.

Option one, store start IP end IP

```
   class IPmodel(models.Model):
      start_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
      end_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
```

Option 2, store the IP and a network mask

```
   class IPmodel(models.Model):
      start_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
      mask = models.IntegerField()
```

If you were to use option 1, your code might look like

```
IPmodel.objects.create(start_ip='192.168.1.0',end_ip='192.168.1.255')
IPmodel.objects.filter(end_ip__gt='192.168.1.10').filter(start_ip__lt='192.168.1.10')
```

If you used option 2, you would need to use F functions and the standard network address calculations to do your filtering.

Comment: and how do I query "is ip is in table"?

Comment: Is it more efficient then storing each IP separately? In terms of query speed

Comment: Both in terms of speed and storage.